# How to make delegate command wait untill execute get completed

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, wait

I am having one Delegate command as like below:

```
  public static DelegateCommand CreateCommand<TState, TTrigger>(this StateMachine<TState, TTrigger> stateMachine, TTrigger trigger, Action execute = null, Func<bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        if (canExecute == null)
        {
            canExecute = () => true;
        }

        if (execute == null)
        {
            execute = () => { };
        }

        return new DelegateCommand(
            executeMethod: async () =>
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    execute();
                });
                if (stateMachine.CanFire(trigger))
                {
                    stateMachine.Fire(trigger);
                }
            },
            canExecuteMethod: () => canExecute());
    }
```

the below code snippet should not be get executed untill the method "execute()" get completed.

```
if (stateMachine.CanFire(trigger))
                {
                    stateMachine.Fire(trigger);
                }
```

Currently my applicaton working in a asynchronous manner, so before the execute() getting completed it goes to the next line. I have tried

> await also,but it is not waiting. What is am missing here?

Comment: How is the execute() action implemented?

Comment: If this returns immediately, so will your task.

Comment: Execute Method will get invoked on button click event.inside execute action am having n number of functions which are executed asynchronously. my execute should wait until the nth function completes its execution.so that i set await to execute(), but its not working as expected.

Comment: execute() cannot be asynchronous because you are not awaiting it. So this won't work. That's why should never use await in a void method.

Comment: Oh! Is there any other ways to achieve the thing i need. Without setting async to execute() also it is working in the same way, since my whole application is asynchronous one

Comment: You can't await a sync void method. What you could possibly do is to change the type of the execute parameter from Action to Task and await the Task. An Action is not supposed to be async.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                execute();
            }).ContinueWith(
            x =>
            {
                stateMachine.Fire(trigger);
            });
```